Alien show concept on Netflix where Earth is taken over by aliens who hunted humans
It was an end of the world scenario where aliens had taken over the Earth and hunted humans, the captured ones would be stored in a greenhouse as the air was not breathable. Humans would be experimented on and then sent back out to try and find more humans.
There remaining humans would fight to survive.
I recall a third being, depicted as almost a god /fairy creature, though no doubt it will still be an alien, and it wasn't shown if this alien was good or bad.
In the concept, I recall a human who had mutated from experiments, walking down the street with 2 aliens, shouting that the aliens have safe greenhouses for them etc

In the concept, I recall a human who had mutated from experiments, walking down the street with 2 aliens, shouting that the aliens have safe greenhouses for them etc

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When was it that you saw this?  Was it live-action or animated?

Might it be Neil Blomkamp's Rakka?

In the near future, Earth will be attacked by technologically superior and highly aggressive reptilian aliens called the Klum (pronounced "klume"). Humanity is nearing extinction with millions dead or enslaved. The Klum transform the Earth in favor of their own ideal living conditions. They do this at first by burning forests and destroying cities. Then they build megastructures that alter the atmosphere by pumping out methane. The gas makes it progressively harder for terrestrial life to breathe. And it warms the climate, which leads to flooding of coastal cities.
The story begins in 2020, from the viewpoint of resistance fighters in Texas, a group of US Army soldiers and many others who have banded together. Most human survivors live underground or among ruins. They have barely enough provisions, weapons, and ammunition. The humans fight by using whatever they can against the primary Klum weapon: an omnipresent nanite in their weaponry, and telepathic control over any human that makes direct eye contact with them.
The resistance makes "brain-barriers" that block this mind control. The Klum know, however, that a scarcity of materials means a scarcity of brain barriers. They hope, therefore, to win a war of attrition against the human survivors.
Some prisoners are living incubators for the Klum's young, which inevitably kills the victims. Others are dissected. Still other humans are converted into human loudspeakers that urge humans to surrender into "conservatories". Very few humans ever escape.
After the Klum destroy a militia convoy with an airstrike, one of the surviving soldiers witnesses an angel-like being materialize from thin air. The narration describes ″them″ as mankind's saviours.


A search for netflix show aliens terraform earth brought me to this Reddit thread.
Trailer



Full Film




I knew there was something suspicious about Heidi Klum. She's a bit too attractive and clever to be fully human.
